# RLMRealm, when removing an object, how to remove it from references in RLMArray

Tags: swift, realm

I'm working on a shopping list app using RLMRealm. I have an Item object that represents the name of an item you might shop for. I also have a ShoppingList, which holds an RLMArray of Items. If I remove an Item is there an easy way to remove that item from each array it might exist in?

I started with this:

```
// Look for this item in shoppingList.list and remove also 
for shoppingList in ShoppingList.allObjects() {
    for i in 0..<(shoppingList as ShoppingList).list.count {
        if ((shoppingList as ShoppingList).list[i] as ShoppingItem).item == item {
            (shoppingList as ShoppingList).list.removeObjectAtIndex(i)
        }
    }
}
```

Which isn't working. it doesn't throw any errors, it just seems to leave empty items.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue. I'm not sure. Did you start/commit transaction?

Answer (score 0):

First off, as romanvbabenko mentions, you need to perform changes like this inside a write transaction.

Second off, you cannot safely mutate an `RLMResults` or an `RLMArray` while you are mutating it -- in future versions of Realm, that will cause an exception to be thrown.

The best way to do this would be the following:

`item.realm.deleteObjects(item.linkingObjectsOfClass(ShoppingList.self, forProperty: "list"))`